# Conditional expectation of asymptotically independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose that  $W_n \to W_{\infty}$ a.s.   where $W_{\infty}$ is independent of random variable $V$.   Moreover, suppose that $E[|V|]<\infty$.

Is it true that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to\infty} E[V|W_n]=  E[V|W_\infty]=E[V] \text{ a.s.}
\end{align}

The last equality is of course trivial. Therefore, I am looking the proof of the first.   This looks like some kind of continuity result, and I am actually not sure if it holds.   If the result doesn't hold, I would like to know what extra conditions can be added for it to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be any integrable random variable, $Y=V$ and $W_n=Y/n$. Then $W_n\to 0=:W_\infty$ which is independent of $V$ but the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $W_n$ is the same as that generated by $V$ hence $\mathbb E\left[V\mid W_n\right]=V$ and we get a counter-example for any non-degenerated $V$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample.  Do you think we can prove this under some additional assumptions?

Comment: The only non trivial thing I have in head is when the sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $(\sigma\left(W_n\right))_n$ is non-increasing.

Comment: You mean when it is a filtration?

Comment: A reversed filtration, yes.

Comment: That would be the martingale convergence, right?

Comment: Exactly. Can you say more about the context which led you to this question? I would help to determine exactly which kind of conditions you need.

Comment: In my specific setting $W_n= \frac{1}{n}V+U$ where $U$ is independent of $V$. We can take $U$ to be standard normal.   Do you think we can show that this is a reverse filtration?

Comment: Maybe for some visilibity you could ask this as a separated question.