# Limit of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-expectation

I am working with conditional expectations and am trying to derive a limit property.

Consider $(_)_{\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of square integrable random variables, that converge in $L^2$ to a square integrable random variable $Y$. Additionally assume that $\mathbb E[Y_n\mid Y]=Y_n$ (for example, $Y_n$ is a sequence of discrete quantizers of $Y$).

Is there anyway at all of guaranteeing that for some other $X$ in $L^2$, and for some form of convergence ($L^2, \mathbb P$ etc.) :
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\mathbb E[X\mid Y_n]=\mathbb E[X\mid Y].$$

I am aware of the following similar question :

[Conditional expectation of asymptotically independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3096326/321264)

but in that case $\mathbb E[Y_n\mid Y]=Y_n$ does not hold...

With a $L^2$-projection approach to conditional expectation, and with $Y_n$ converging in $L^2$ to $Y$, I keep thinking there must be some way of getting this to work... But maybe it just won't.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Please always use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Answer (score 0):

This is true if $\{\sigma(Y_n)\}$ is an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-fields s.t. $\sigma(Y_n)\nearrow \sigma(Y)$. In this case (see Theorem 4.6.8 on page 247 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)),
$$
\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y_n]\to \mathsf{E}[X\mid Y]\quad\text{a.s. and in $L^1$}.
$$
For example, this holds when $Y_n=2^{-n}\lceil 2^nY\rceil$.

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately, in my setting it is not the case...